# wamp mysql cannot connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, mysql-error-1130

hello
i tried to follow an online tut for setting password in mysql and this has now led to errors that i cannot recover from.

1) phpMyAdmin-2.11.10
   this gives login box with message underneath: cannot load mcrypt. i have enabled in wamp and also put libmcrypt.dll in windows and windows\system32 folders. but still get message.if i put root in login box with no pass, this leads to second error.

2) mysql error

## 1130 - Host 'localhost' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

i have tried various fixes but nothing seems to work. i would be grateful for any help. thanks

phpMyAdmin-2.11.10
mysql4.1.22
php4.4.7

phpmyadmin config.inc.php

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use scripts/setup.php
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 *
 * @version $Id: config.sample.inc.php 12304 2009-03-24 12:56:58Z nijel $
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/* User for advanced features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

?>
```

Comment: It sounds like the username you are login in MySQL with (via phpmyadmin) has it's "host" field set to something other than "localhost" or "%" (any host).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Wamp comes with phpMyAdmin already configured. What tutorial did you have used?

LE:

Is this the root user or other account? If I were you, I would backup my data ( files and sql ), do a fresh wamp install ( the latest version not the one in your tutorial ) and do the following:

- go to Start -> Run , enter cmd
- use cd command to navigate where mysql.exe is installed

Use the following commands :

```
mysql>
mysql>update mysql.user SET password=password("newpassword") hit enter
mysql>where user="root"; hit enter
Query OK


mysql>Flush Privileges; hit enter
Query OK
mysql>quit hit enter
mysql>bye
```

Then go to phpMyAdmin config.inc and edit

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'newpassword';
```

Restart the WAMP server and should be ok now.

Comment: Did you've double checked that the mcrypt extension is enabled in php? If it is, try and restart the whole Wamp setup.

Comment: To get no error when you have no password, you have to add in the config.inc.php file $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

Comment: @Bdesign i have and still the same. i have managed to get into phpmyadmin after several error messages but it now tells my that i cannot create databases. in user in mysql table i have all priviliges saying yes. grrrrrr

Comment: ok. now i can login but each time i select a table i have to login again and i get message localhost is not allowed to connect. also, i still do not have priviliges to create db. thanks

Comment: update. i am now getting this message when i have just logged in: No activity within 1800 seconds; please log in again. i only get it when i click the user table in the mysql db. thanks

Comment: Hmmm, I presume that you have Cookies enabled. For the logged in thing, you cand go to config.inc.php , search for auth_type and change it to "http" . This way you should never get logged out until you close your browser.

Comment: thank you for your help. i have removed old wamp and installed new version and all seems well. i do have one question though. what is the correct way to set a password for mysql or user with all prviliges using the version i posted. thanks

Comment: Well, the main problem is how to set the password for the root user. But if you want to set a password for a mysql user just go in phpMyAdmin -> Privileges . There you can add a new user, just don't forget to have set "Use text field", not "No password". And about the privileges, if you want them all, you just have to click on Check All link.  But if you plan to put online this server, this is a very very bad idea. Using wamp for an online server is a bad idea.